# How to select nth row of each group in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this

| member_id | book_title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | one-one |
| 1 | one-two |
| 1 | one-three |
| 2 | two-one |
| 2 | two-two |
| 2 | two-three |

I want to group by `member_id` and 3rd book title, so if I run the query, the result must be:

| member_id | book_title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | one-three |
| 2 | two-three |

Comment: You would need column(s) that persist `2` and `3` instead of the text `two-three`.

Comment: What means "group by member_id and 3rd book title", 3rd book title is a value not a column. You can select every member_id that has 3rd book title using regex.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming with "3rd book title" you mean "*the third book if sorted alphabetically by title*" this can be achieved using window functions:

```
select member_id, book_title
from (
   select member_id, book_title, 
          row_number() over (partition by member_id order by book_title) as rn
   from the_table
) t
where rn = 3;
```

Note that this won't return members that have less than 3 books assigned.